# When piping data to a command in bash, can other processes snoop on the data?

Tags: linux, bash, security

An example of this is:

```
cat pass.txt | docker login -u jarjarbinks --password-stdin=true
```

Can another unprivileged process snoop on the data being transferred through the anonymous FIFO?

Comment: `cat pass.txt | docker` is a typical [useless use of cat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11710552/7939871)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

does the process belong to the same user running this?

1. **YES**: well, just as you can attach a debugger to your own processes, another process run by your user (assuming you have the `SYS_PTRACE` capability, but you usually do) can just snoop on the system calls needed to read the stdin file descriptor.
2. **NO**: "standard" unix user separation applies and the other user can't interfere with your processes, their memory or file descriptors.